# woocommerce: hide stock status field for certain product type (backend)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, field, hide, hook

I want to remove/hide the field "stock status" in the admin backend (inventory tab) for a certain product type.

I managed to do something similar to hide one of the tabs, here is the code for that:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', function($tabs) {

   array_push($tabs['shipping']['class'], 'hide_if_test_product');
   return $tabs;

}, 10, 1);
```

This adds the class "hide_if_test_product" to the `<li>` tag wrapped arount the shipping tab, so that it will be hidden when the product type "test_product" is selected.

Now I would need to do the same with a text field within another tab (I can't hide the entire tab this time, because I still need the other text field in that tab), but I have no idea how to do something similiar like in the code above but for a field, not a tab. I found out that the right hook/filter for the stock status field might be "woocommerce_product_options_stock_status" but what next? I just can't figure it out. :-(

Thanks a lot,

Chups